# How to spy on a Marionette view that extends an external library with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, testing, bdd, jasmine, marionette

I have a view who extends an external library (let's call it ExtLib) also based on backbone marionette. Basically this lib is a wrapper of common views that share behaviours (e.g. DetailsView, FormView, etc..). So, let's say I have something like this:

```
MyApp.module('Views', function(Views, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {

    Views.MyDetailsView = Marionette.ExtLib.DetailsView.extend({
        options: {
            fields: [
                // ...
            ],
            myFunction: function() {
                // ...
            }
        }
    });    
});
```

In my Jasmine test, I call a controller method that creates an instance of MyDetailsView.

```
it('does what it should', function() {
    // ...

    controller.showDetails();

    // my expectations
});
```

Actually, the method in controller just creates the view and render it (into a layout's region).

```
showDetails: function(story) {
    var container = new App.Layouts.DetailsLayout();
    var myDetailsView = new App.Views.MyDetailsView({
        model: story
    });

    container.details.show(storyDetailsView);
}
```

Finally, here's the error that i get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/myapp/js/lib/underscore/underscore-min.js?_debugResources=y&n=1354890505115:30:350), <anonymous>:17:35)
at c (http://localhost:8080/myapp/js/lib/underscore/underscore-min.js?_debugResources=y&n=1354890505115:30:430)
at Object.Backbone.Marionette.Renderer.render (http://localhost:8080/myapp/js/backbone-app/conf/renderer.js?_debugResources=y&n=1354890505115:9:17)
at r.ItemView.r.View.extend.render (http://localhost:8080/myapp/js/lib/backbone/backbone.marionette.min.js?_debugResources=y&n=1354890505115:13:4719)
at  Backbone.Marionette.ExtLib.ExtLib.DetailsView.Backbone.Marionette.View.extend.renderFieldView (http://localhost:8080/myapp/js/lib/backbone.marionette.extlib.min.js?_debugResources=y&n=1354890505115:395:14)
// etc...
```

I think that the problem is that jasmine is not aware of ExtLib. How can I spy on that renderFieldView to avoid the error?

Thanks in advance, as always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think that the problem is that jasmine is not aware of ExtLib.

I can't tell from that stack trace whether your diagnosis is correct; but to verify that, you can view source on the Jasmine runner and see if ExtLib is included in the runner's page.

If ExtLib is *not* included, then the fix depends on how you're running Jasmine.  If you're using the Jasmine gem and you have a jasmine.yml file, you'll want to edit jasmine.yml to include ExtLib.  If you have a "simple" configuration and you are maintaining Jasmine's included Javascript files by hand, then you'll need to add a line to include ExtLib in the runner's source file.